# How to prevent errors when working with procedures in recursive functions?

Tags: racket

I am trying to create a group of procedures that, together, count the frequency of word(s) in a list. The format of the output should be like the following: `'(("happy" 132) ("amazing" 2) ("funny" 600) ("death" 0))`.

I have made this so far:

```
(define count-words
  (lambda (list-of-words filename)
    (if (null? list-of-words)
        0
        (cons (tally-value (file->words filename) (car list-of-words)) (count-words (cdr list-of-words (file->words filename)))))
```

It works fine when only given one word in the search list, but when it attempts to search for the second word, it gives the following error:

```
file->words: contract violation
  expected: string?
  given: '("Sam" "Sam" "Sam" "Sam" "Sam" "Sam" "Sam" "Sam" "Sam" "Sam" "Sam" "Sam" "Sam" "Sam" "Sam" "Sam" "Sam" "Sam" "Sam" "Sam" "Sam" "Sam" "Sam" "Sam" "Sam" "Sam" "Sam" "Sam" "Sam" "Sam" "Sam" "Sam" "Sam" "Sam" "Sam" "Sam" "Sam" "Sam" "Sam" "Sam" "Sam"...
```

I believe it is trying to convert the list in the same way it successfully converted the file, which is not possible. How can I prevent my code from rerunning this part of the function and just have it use the list it made in the first go around?

Comment: Sorry if this was not clear. The filename is a txt file split into a list of strings containing individual words. List-of-words is the list of words that I need to be counted from the filename list. There is a cdr that moves to the next element in list-of-words (or at least tries to). Is it in the wrong place?

Comment: Yes, `cdr` is misplaced. And you should call `file->words` only _once_ outside the recursion, and pass the result to this function.

Comment: Sorry if this is a low-level question, but how can I call it only once outside of the recursion and pass it this way? I tried to use a let statement, but I got the same error. Also, I'm not quite sure where else to put `cdr`.

Comment: Simple: you write _two_ functions, not one. In one you call `file->words` and pass the result to the other, which is the one that does the actual recursion. Also, I suggest you go back to your notes or your text book, you need to understand how `cdr` works: `(cdr some-list)` advances the list, and it receives a single parameter.

Comment: Oscar, thank you for your help. I've managed to get my program up and running thanks to your advice.

Comment: I've rolled back your edit. It is not appropriate to add `*(CLOSED)* to the title or edit a solution into the question. If you've found a solution and would like to share it, you can do so by writing an answer in the space provided for that purpose. If you no longer want the question to be answered, you can delete it using the link below the tags.